# UIButton with changing text within a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I am trying to add a "Forgot password" button as a right view of my text field. The text field has custom styling that should also be applied to the button, therefore the button has to be inside of the text field.

What I have so far is this:

```
let forgotPasswordButton = UIButton()
forgotPasswordButton.setTitle("Forgot", for: .normal)
forgotPasswordButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forgotPassword), for: [.touchUpInside])

passwordTextField.rightView = forgotPasswordButton
passwordTextField.rightViewMode = .always
```

The problem is, my button is invisible. After some googling I realised I should set the frame to the button instead of initializing with `.zero`. The problem there though is that the title of the button is localized and therefore has different widths.

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the size from NSString method size :

```
// Create Label
let forgotPasswordButton = UIButton()
forgotPasswordButton.backgroundColor = .red

// Title and font
let title = "Forgot my wallet in the appartment"
let font = forgotPasswordButton.titleLabel?.font

// Set title
forgotPasswordButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

// Get size of title
let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
let size = (title as NSString).size(attributes: fontAttributes)

// Set frame using found size
forgotPasswordButton.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
```

Then you do your logic with the size.

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to shrink the label, I want to leave the font size as is and accordingly take up more or less space on the right side of the text field.

Comment: Ok sorry. I didn't understand. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

U can create a custom class based UITextfield , and override this selector like this:

```

```
override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.rightViewRect(forBounds: bounds);
        rect.size.width = rect.size.width*2;
        rect.size.height = rect.size.height*2;
        return rect;
    }
```

```

U can custom the rect by your need in this way;

Comment: This does not solve the problem of having the exact width based on the text of the button title.

Comment: You can get the button's width with your button title, and then set the button's width in this way.